# loop through i = 1 to n rows, find last used column in each row and copy its data to column AA1 same row VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with a part where I 'd like macro to loop through variable number of rows. I need to find last used column in each row and copy its content to column AA1 same row. Number of columns in each rows is also variable and will change as the number of columns is a result of text to copy action. I will never know how much rows and columns I will have.

The reason for this is that the last used column will have a key that I will be using later to vlookup data from another sheet.
Kindly help. I tried to record this by selecting colum AA1 first and then going left with ctrl+shiftlike this, then pasting it to column 'AB1' that way I would have all the codes in one column. But when I try to loop it does not work.

```
Range("AA1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AB1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZNW.jpg)

Here is what I put together so far for this loop:

```
Sub newmak()

Dim i
Dim n
n = Range("A" & Range("A:A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To n

'==================================that part is not working

                        Cells(i, Columns.Count).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        Range("a" & i, 27).Select '<--??
                        Selection.PasteSpecial

'==================================

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To find last column LETTER on this row

```
LastColLtr = Split(Cells(1, Range("ZZ" & RN1).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address, "$")(1)
```

To find last column NUMBER on this row

```
LastColNum = Range("ZZ" & RN1).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim i as long
i = 1

do until isempty(activesheet.cells(i, 1).value)
  dim v as variant

  if isempty(activesheet.cells(i, 2).value) then
    v = activesheet.cells(i, 1).value
  else
    v = activesheet.cells(i, 1).end(xltoright).value
  end if

  activesheet.cells(i, "AB").value = v
  i = i + 1
loop
```